# How to create a dynamic online Windows Installer with a key?

Tags: applications, installer

I'm creating an application which needs to have a key file based product activation.

If a user purchases the application, the key file may have to be attached to the application EXE file dynamically (may be online) and package it to an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer. The user downloads the application from a server or repository.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can embed custom data in the `Binary` table in an MSI file. When a customer downloads your installer you could perform a custom action and copy the base MSI, insert their license and provide the file to download.

I think that you're over complicating this. I think you would be far better off shipping an unregistered installer and providing the user the facility to input their license data.

Comment: "... input their license data" means entering the key manually or attaching a key file ? Can you please explain more clearly how to do with an example. Thank you.